# Executing Javascript Code From Objective C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have some javascript code that I need to execute from an objective-c (iPhone) app.

The javascript code needs some of the values from the iPhone app.  What I mean is, there is a spot in the iPhone app (a `textbox`) for a user to type their name.  Then the javascript code that runs will be: `alert(name)`

where the `name` variable is really `textbox.text`

How can I do this from objective-c, without relying on an external webserver?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at those, but I'm afraid neither offers what I'm looking for -- most seem to rely on an external server.

Comment: Is it a major problem if my javascript does not have a return value?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UIWebView` and inject a `<script>` tag containing the JavaScript using `[webview loadHTMLString: html]`

Comment: Wouldn't that rely on a webserver, though?

Comment: No, `loadHTMLString` takes standalone HTML, no need for a web server.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to make the webView invisible?

Comment: Yes, all `UIView` objects have a `hidden` property

Comment: Is it a major problem if my javascript does not have a return value?

Comment: It's a massive overkill though. WebView takes an appreciable amount of time to load and initialize. If all you need is JavaScript per se (as opposed to, say, the DOM library, of which `alert` is part), maybe a standalone JS interpreter would do better.

Comment: Wait... in the javascript how do I reference textbox.text? Since that's part of the objective C?